# Does Russia intervene more on the world stage than its peers?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, syria, foreign-interference, republic-of-georgia

Follow-up question to Fizz's comment in [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69156/why-does-russia-view-missile-defense-as-a-strategic-threat).

> "their foreign policy tends to be non-interventionist". Except in neighboring countries Georgia (2008), Ukraine (2014+) and where they have bases they want to keep like in Syria. Never mind Wagner, which has broader reach and some deniability, albeit fewer capabilities than regular forces.

Is it actually the case that Russia has intervened in foreign countries more than other countries, in spite of saying their foreign policy is non-interventionist?

For the purposes of this question I'm most interested in other members of the UN Security Council. "Intervention" is also difficult to define; as a starting point I take it to mean "to deploy your personnel to that country to advance your country's policy goals, against the wishes of that country". So e.g.:

- The US does not intervene in Japan by having a military base in Okinawa.
- Russia does not intervene in the US by remotely hacking their servers.
- But Russia would be intervening in the US if they sent an operative to the US to physically destroy the servers.

Under this definition Russia's actions in Georgia (2008) and Ukraine (2014+) are interventions, but Syria is not.

The period I'm interested in is the period since Putin first became President of Russia, i.e. post-2000, including the period when Medvedev was president.

Comment: If anyone has a better definition of "intervention" feel free to share.

Comment: I am afraid this will be very difficult to evaluate. Your definition ("to deploy your personnel to that country to advance your country's policy goals, against the wishes of that country") would include spying : https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-55258790 
And I am not sure why it would exclude Syria. Russia's intervention might have been welcome by Assad, but not by Kurds, Alepan, Ghouta rebels and probably most Syrians.
And then, comparing to "other countries" is vague. Luxemburg, Uruguay, Gabon or Slovakia have not deployed personnel abroad (AFAIK) for different reasons.

Comment: @Evargalo spying wouldn't be for advancing policy goals, would it? It would only be for acquisition of information. As for Syria, it has an internationally recognized government, which is something that can be unambiguously defined and hence represents the country's wishes. I'm aware the question is hard, but that's why I ask it; if it were easy I'd probably be able to Google.

Comment: Excluding intervention in a foreign civil war is quite a caveat you came up with. Russia didn't just build a base in Syria, they bombed the crap out of the factions opposing Assad, by many accounts allowing him to win the war.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_military_intervention_in_the_Syrian_civil_war

Comment: @Fizz sure, but do you have a better definition of "intervention"?

Comment: @Allure My instinctive reaction would have been to say that the only purpose of getting information through spying **is** advancing one's policy goals. But I won't argue too much in comments since I honestly don't what to suggest to improve your question.

Comment: Generally, the line is drawn at intervening with troops in a combat role... 
although it can be murky at times, e.g. the Soviets secretly sent pilots to fight the US in the Korean war etc. The Wagner business is in a sense continuing that tradition.

Comment: It's trivially true that Russia is more interventionist than most countries, since most countries are relatively small and do not have the resources to fight many, if any, non-defensive wars. On the other hand, it is undoubtedly less interventionist than the USA. Perhaps it would be more useful to compare it to other countries with similar or larger military capabilities.

Comment: See e.g. https://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780199743292/obo-9780199743292-0047.xml for def, but it's by no mean universally accepted, https://www.britannica.com/topic/interventionism says something a bit different. On the line I mentioned earlier https://www.jstor.org/stable/2600156

Comment: @Obie2.0 that's why the question originally said other members of the UN Security council, but that line was edited out.

Comment: @Fizz the Brittanica link defines it "as a threatening act that is unwelcome by the target of one’s intervention", which still excludes Syria, unless you consider the factions opposing Assad as the ones that don't welcome the intervention. But if you do that, then the events in Crimea ceases to be an intervention (since Crimea welcomed the intervention) and the same goes for Georgia (South Ossetia & Abkhazia also welcomed the intervention). I am not convinced that definition is better.

Comment: While no definition is perfect, I can't see the definition in the question as being too useful. It encompasses much of what one might think of a *militarism*, but excludes too much of what one might think of as interventions. For instance, if the United States were to provide funding and weapons to Venezuelan rebels to assassinate Maduro, that would not be an intervention. If China were to park a few aircraft carriers outside of Taiwan's territorial waters and shoot anyone trying to come near, that would not be an intervention. If Russia were to refuse to export to any pro-EU countries, etc.

Comment: In other words, by only including the deployment of personnel to a country, it excludes a number of very effective actions for foreign intervention.

Comment: @Obie2.0 we can see the problem from what you've written though: by demanding that 'intervention' includes more than deployment of personnel to a country, you contradict Fizz's position above that intervention is "intervening with troops in a combat role". The definition is difficult, but one still has to adopt some definition, and it looks like most people will not agree on what that definition should be.

Comment: "In 2013, the US Special Operations Command (SOCOM) — one of the nine organizational units that make up the Unified Combatant Command — had special operations forces (SOFs) in 134 countries, where they were either involved in combat, special missions, or advising and training foreign forces." Does propping up puppet dictators count as intervention?

Comment: @KeithMcClary by the definition in the OP, probably not, since the puppet dictators presumably welcome the SOFs.

Comment: I still don't understand the definitions... remotely hacking US servers does not count, yet some of the hacking was to gain access to political information _explicitly_ to be used to affect the politics of the US... how is that NOT intervention?

Comment: @CGCampbell is the person using the information to affect the politics of the US in the US? If not, then it's not intervention.

Comment: Probably depends on how you define peers. Economically, or size of population or size of military? There are more countries in the world than just UN security council members.

Comment: It is not clear that it is possible or useful to consider any other country a "peer" of Russia. Arguably the best modern historical analogy would be to the decline of the Ottoman Empire.

Answer (score 1):

> "Intervention" is also difficult to define; as a starting point I take it to mean "to deploy your personnel to that country to advance your country's policy goals, against the wishes of that country". So e.g.:

It is standard fare for Russia to argue that its intervention in Syria was legal, according to international law. But that doesn't make it a non-intervention, as you want to push/define the term. Rather [it's](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40802-019-00133-7) "intervention by invitation".

> With the recent interventions by invitation by France in Mali, the US-led coalition in Iraq, Saudi Arabia in Yemen, Russia in Syria, and most recently by the Economic Community of West African States (ECOWAS) in The Gambia, the issue has not only become topical again, but also controversial. **Intervention by invitation** has accordingly attracted increased attention among international legal scholars. Most of these academic discussions have centred on issues such as who represents the government of a state and whether an intervention by invitation is allowed when the state is engaged in a civil war.
>
> [...] According to Georg Nolte, ‘[t]he expression “intervention by invitation” is mostly used as a shorthand for military intervention by foreign troops in an internal armed conflict at the invitation of the government of the State concerned’. [...]
>
> The term intervention is contrasted with the use of force and the entire concept of intervention by invitation is differentiated from collective self-defence. [...] intervention by invitation relates not only to actions against non-state actors, but also against states, as long as the fighting is limited to the inviting state’s territory. [...] intervention by invitation might not be its proper name, as it does not deal solely with an intervention, but actually deals with a use of force, which is a separate (but related) notion under international law to which different rules apply. A more appropriate name is therefore the **use of force by invitation**. [...]
>
> An intervention by invitation also fulfils the requirement of intent. The armed forces invited into the state clearly have the intent to use force; that is in fact precisely the reason why they are invited in. The territorial state needs help in its struggle against the opposition. The invited foreign troops are thus present precisely with the intent for them to use force.

The latter point is perhaps the distinction you were trying to make between those kinds of interventions and e.g. interfering in elections by some non-violent means (or spying).

HTH with respect your terminological confusions. I'm not going to try to answer the rest of the Q, for now, but you are essentially talking about the use of force without invitation (from the internationally recognized government). OTOH there's not quite universal agreement that only the government's agreement matters.

> it is at times argued that an intervention by invitation on the side of a government that is engaged in a fight against a liberation movement struggling for its right to self-determination could perhaps constitute a violation of both the political independence of that state and the right to self-determination [...] Some authors take the right to self-determination a step further and equate a struggle for self-determination with any type of civil war situation. It is subsequently argued that an intervention by invitation in any civil war goes against the political independence of the state (or rather that of its people) and violates the right to self-determination.

Comment: Going through the refs for that last issue; there was a 1975 [IDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institut_de_Droit_International) resolution against all forms of interventions in civil wars, but beside it being ignored in practice, in 2011 they came up with a "more specific prohibition against military assistance “when its object is to support an established government against its own population”" https://www.ejiltalk.org/the-airstrikes-against-islamic-state-in-iraq-and-the-alleged-prohibition-on-military-assistance-to-governments-in-civil-wars/

Answer (score -1):

Since 2000, off the top of my head

US: Iraq, Afghanistan, Libya, Syria, Sudan, Yemen (covert support for Saudi war and campaign of mass starvation), Iran (post JCPOA unauthorized sanctions, petroleum blockade, assassination of a prominent leader, stated goal of regime change), China (support of HK independence, economic warfare, pressured Canada to arrest Meng Wanzhou), Australia (sabotaged France sub deal), Germany/Russia (sabotaged NS2 pipeline, then when crunch time, proceeded to send US LNG to asia instead of europe), overt support for regime changes in Ukraine, Georgia, etc, continuing decades long interference in politics much of Latin America (support right wing governments, overt and covert support [funding, political recognition, economic blockade] for attempted regime change in Venezuela)....

Russia:  Georgia, Ukraine, Syria, Armenia (as peacekeepers in the aftermath of the recent conflict with Azerbaijan), probably a handful of other post soviet states. Level of mass death generally far lower than example set by Iraq, Libya, Yemen, Afghanistan etc

Comment: Is the US, with a GDP 11 times bigger than Russia's, a good country to use as a "contemporary" of Russia?

Comment: "overt support for ... Venezuela" "over support ... Israel" ... Does overt support = "to deploy your personnel to that country to advance your country's policy goals, against the wishes of that country"? Please edit your lists to fit the author's criteria. I'm not suggesting the US isn't worse/bad/evil, I'm simply suggesting your list goes beyond what the OP has stipulated.

Comment: I have removed mention of Israel and Palestine as requested, and clarified regarding Venezuela

Comment: I am not sure this answer is too useful, even now that the question has been edited back to focus on (presumably permanent) members of the UN Security Council. Primarily, that's because the USA is a single country, and there are four non-Russia members of the Council, whom the answer does not touch on. Further, most of the examples given for the United States do not meet the stated criteria (which, admittedly, can be argued to be too narrow), because they do not involve personnel being deployed against a country.

Comment: Without talking about France, Britain, and China, all the answer establishes is that Russia is less interventionist than the USA, while not eliminating the possibility that it could still (hypothetically) be the second-most interventionist permanent member of the UNSC. There are other issues with misleading terminology ("economic blockade" and "economic warfare," mainly), but that is the main issue that I see.

Comment: Other than a few weak complaints/objections/criticisms, I don't follow that the US has intervened in the HK situation. There is no dispute the land belongs to China, which has made a promise, at the time the UK handed it over, to keep the system for a certain period but failed to follow through.

Comment: Most countries mentioned either have shown aggressiveness towards the neighboring countries, which could destabilize the region or possess dangerous weapons that the whole world doesn't want to see (N. Korea, Iran, Iraq - which was a mistake). While the US is doing the dirty policing works, China and Russia are sabotaging by supplying materials and technics to those tyrants behind the scene and pretend they are the good guys. That's been the reason Trump wanted the US out of the leading position in the world matters. Then his position has been harshly criticized by the very same complainers.

Comment: @r13- re: HK, in my view, US policy actively interfered in the one part of China that had a western style election system, with the standard tactic of promoting civil unrest like in Jan 6th in Washington, but worse (watch the videos). The result was a disaster.... Re: the places billed as "police action", US under neocon style leadership is demonstrably incompetent, one could say criminally so for places where the body count exceeds 5 figures. Besides the casualties, the result was widespread dislocation of people, economic collapse, starvation, and ruin in the first group of countries listed.

Comment: ... which is to say, it's all a lot more in line with a vindictive imperial power interested in dealing out punishment (and the neocons, who never went away from their positions in the policy bureaucracy, have been happy to say as much), and not so much like any kind of police one would want in their own home country. Anyway, I don't mean to make this all about the US, but the question is comparative, and IMO this is the best comparison or contrast.

Comment: @PeteW - The question seems to have a larger group in mind, and as mentioned previously, this answer does not establish how Russia compares to the other three permanent members of the UNSC.

Comment: @r13 - If having "dangerous weapons that the world does not want to see" were a justification for any type of action, then the United States would have to invade China, France, India, and the UK, among others.

Comment: @Obie2.0 You don't seem to have the clue how these countries behave in view of world security and safety. Use some common sense, please.

Comment: When did Russia intervented in Armenia?

Comment: Russian peacekeepers are in Azerbaijan not Armenia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peacekeeping_operations_in_Nagorno-Karabakh

Comment: Can you please cite your sources and actually spell out your acronyms when you use them in full.

Comment: Almost all of the former Soviet Central Asian Republics and Moldova come to mind.