# Russian Experts on the Credibility of the Russian Nuclear Second Strike Capability

Tags: russian-federation, nuclear-weapons, geopolitics, nato

From *Western* news reports about Russian government statements, Russia seems concerned that NATO forces in the ex-Communist states would endanger the Russian strategic deterrence (which include a second strike capability to retaliate after a first strike). I would have thought that the Russian [second strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_strike) capability (nuclear forces that would survive an enemy first strike and inflict unacceptable damage on the attacker) remains unaffected by a small number of interceptors e.g. in Romania or Poland. Four questions, which are really one:

What is the Russian view on the state of the Russian nuclear forces?

- How operational is the early warning and command and control systems?
- How operational are the Russian ballistic missile submarines? How many of them are on patrol in an average month?
- Are the road-mobile ICBM concentrated in easy-to-hit locations?
- Or are they afraid of precedents, not of any *current* degradation of MAD?

Note that I'm not asking about **actual** readiness, which would surely be classified information. I'm asking what non-government researchers in Russia (not in the West) **think** about it, especially researchers who influence public opinion. Are there any English-language sources on this?

---

Follow-up: I found this [RAND study](https://www.rand.org/pubs/research_reports/RRA1094-1.html) which acknowledges Russian concerns. Still not a Russian source, but quoting many.

Comment: I've never read anything credible on the topic and not much at all. And I read quite a lot of stuff.

Comment: [Why is having a NATO missile-defense launch system such a big deal for Russia?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/38626/why-is-having-a-nato-missile-defense-launch-system-such-a-big-deal-for-russia) asks the same question.  And my [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/38638/13162) gives a link to a video of Putin's speech in which he states the answer directly.  The voice-over translation to English does not interfere with the original (in Russian).  So you can actually hear what he said on the topic.

Comment: @grovkin, your answer is about fears of receiving a *first* strike, while I wondered about their ability to deliver a *second* strike. Related, but not quite the same.

Comment: @o.m. it is related because the Russians don't buy the premise that the interceptors would remain interceptors.  You are asking why would they fear X (since f(x) is not a threat to them).  But they haven't said that they are afraid of f(x).  They have expressed a firm believe that X would become Y.  Answering "they don't" is an on-topic answer to the question "why do they?"

Comment: @grovkin, my question was about what happens **after** a hypothetical first strike.

Comment: You are not stating the premise "Russia seems concerned that NATO forces in the ex-Communist states would endanger the Russian strategic deterrence" as a hypothetical.  I guess editing it to make it a hypothetical would change that.

Comment: @grovkin, I added a remark in that regard even if *I* consider it unnecessary.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, either a conventional or a nuclear counterforce attack. I don't believe the West is capable of a conventional counterforce attack *yet*.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, during the Cold War it was apparently understood that a (conventional) attack on nuclear command-and-control infrastructure was the equivalent of an attack on the nuclear forces, and that was understood to be the equivalent of a nuclear attack.